# Linux: Removing files that don't contain all the words specified

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell

Inside a directory, how can I delete files that lack any of the words specified, so that only files that contain ALL the words are left? I tried to write a simple bash shell script using grep and rm commands, but I got lost. I am totally new to Linux, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

How about:

```
grep -L foo *.txt | xargs rm
grep -L bar *.txt | xargs rm
```

If a file does ***not*** contain `foo`, then the first line will remove it.

If a file does ***not*** contain `bar`, then the second line will remove it.

Only files containing both `foo` and `bar` should be left

```
-L, --files-without-match
     Suppress normal output; instead print the  name  of  each  input
     file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The
     scanning will stop on the first match.
```

See also [@Mykola Golubyev's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614654/linux-removing-files-that-dont-contain-all-the-words-specified/614727#614727) for placing in a loop.

Comment: i think files with foo OR bar, will be deleted with this .

Comment: I think -v is the correct way to negate the grep, since it wont stop on first match?

Comment: No, -v will return all LINES that do not include the word.

Answer (score 11):

```
list=`Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5`
for word in $list
    grep -L $word *.txt | xargs rm
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Addition to the answers above: Use the newline character as delimiter to handle file names with spaces!

```
grep -L $word $file | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Answer (score 1):

grep -L word | xargs rm

Answer (score 1):

To do the same matching filenames (not the contents of files as most of the solutions above) you can use the following:

```
for file in `ls --color=never | grep -ve "\(foo\|bar\)"`
do
   rm $file
done
```

As per comments:

```
for file in `ls`
```

shouldn't be used. The below does the same thing without using the `ls`

```
for file in *
do
  if [ x`echo $file | grep -ve "\(test1\|test3\)"` == x ]; then
    rm $file
  fi
done
```

The -ve reverses the search for the regexp pattern for either foo or bar in the filename.
Any further words to be added to the list need to be separated by \|
e.g. one\|two\|three

Comment: For file in 'ls' is a bad idea.

Comment: Good point. Edited accordingly, but I don't like how that complicates it.
Can you think of a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the file-list:

```
rm flist
```

Then, for each of the words, add the file to the filelist if it contains that word:

```
grep -l WORD * >>flist
```

Then sort, uniqify and get a count:

```
sort flist | uniq -c >flist_with_count
```

All those files in flsit_with_count that don't have the number of words should be deleted. The format will be:

```
2 file1
7 file2
8 file3
8 file4
```

If there were 8 words, then file1 and file2 should be deleted. I'll leave the writing/testing of the script to you.

Okay, you convinced me, here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf flist
for word in fopen fclose main ; do
    grep -l ${word} *.c >>flist
done
rm $(sort flist | uniq -c | awk '$1 != 3 {print $2} {}')
```

This removes the files in the directory that didn't have all three words:

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this but it may break 
if the patterns contain *shell* or *grep* meta characters:

(in this example *one two three* are the patterns)

```
for f in *; do
  unset cmd
  for p in one two three; do
    cmd="fgrep \"$p\" \"$f\" && $cmd"
  done
  eval "$cmd" >/dev/null || rm "$f"  
done
```

Answer (score -1):

This will remove all files that doesn't contain words *Ping* or *Sent*

```
grep -L 'Ping\|Sent' * | xargs rm
```

Comment: This will not remove files that only contain one of the Words.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that already and hit delete, but that was too late.